# proving a statement about average value of a function over a region and a periodic function

Tags: functional-analysis, limits, definite-integrals, average, periodic-functions

Let's say I've a function $f:[0,\infty]\to\mathbb{R}$ and it is periodic with $T$. If we take a look at the average value of this function over the hole region we can write:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\int_0^nf(x)dx=\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Tf(x)dx$$

But how can prove that that is indeed true?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2765597/65203

Comment: @YvesDaoust what is the theorem called?

Comment: You might want to assume that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable on $[0, T]$...

Comment: @user251257 I do not know what that means :(

Comment: No idea. I am not sure that this simple property deserves a name.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If it is so easy there must be a easy proof :)

Comment: @Looper it means, that the Integrals are well-defined and do exist.

Comment: @user251257 of course we assume that the integral exists

Comment: Hint: compare $\frac1n \int_0^n f$ to $\frac1{kT}\int_0^{kT} f$ where $kT \le n \le (k+1)T$.

Comment: @Looper: I pointed you to a proof. Take the time to read.